# One-to-one relationships between entities in the Python Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is to possible to create one-to-one relations in the Python version of Google App Engine? I know it is possible in [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - just use a ReferenceProperty that references an entity not referenced by anything else.

Comment: So there is no way to enforce the constraint

Comment: I don't believe there is in Java, either. You could have each entity mutually reference the other, and check the reference any time you use it, I suppose. What's your use-case?

Comment: Java provides it [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_One_Relationships). I don't have a use case atm, just seems like a logical thing to have

Comment: That's an 'owned' relationship, so it's equivalent to a parent entity in Python. Simply creating an entity with parent=other_entity and a known key is equivalent to this.